# Combining keys by similar values in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to combine keys when they have similar values, and expect the result as a string. Actually I had no idea how to achieve this, although I run a few tests.

```
$array = array(
  'a' => 65,
  'b' => 31,
  'c' => 100,
  'd' => 31,
  'e' => 31,
  'f' => 31,
  'h' => 23,
  'i' => 23,
  'j' => 23,
  'k' => 23,
  'l' => 48,
  'm' => 48,
);

$results = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  // This is my attempt among others to no luck.
  // Can not use array_key_exists because values are unpredictable.
  $similars[$v] = $k;
  $results[$v] = implode(", ", array_unique($similars)) . ' : ' . $v;
}

var_dump(implode("\n ", $results));
```

You can view the output:
http://codepad.org/ECekF3dq

I am almost there, but obviously wrong :(

**Not expected:**

```
string(72) "a : 65
 a, f, c : 31
 a, b, c : 100
 a, f, c, k : 23
 a, f, c, k, m : 48"
```

**Expected:**

```
a : 65
b, d, e, f : 31
c : 100
h, i, j, k : 23
l, m : 48
```

Those with the same values should collapse as one line.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make `$similars` into an array of arrays.  That way you can keep *all* the keys with that value.

```
$results = array();
$similars = array();

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  if(!isset($similars[$v])){
    $similars[$v] = array($k);
  }
  else{
    $similars[$v][] = $k;
  }

  $results[$v] = implode(", ", $similars[$v]) . ' : ' . $v;
}

var_dump(implode("\n ", $results));
```

Comment: Thanks. One loop looks just simpler.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more elegant way of doing this, but I'd probably use two simple foreach loops:

```
function parseArray($data)
{
    $tmp = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
        // Check if we already created this key
        if (isset($tmp[$item])) {
            // Append if so
            $tmp[$item] .= ', '.$key;
        } else {
            // Init if not
            $tmp[$item] = $key;
        }
    }

    // Now we stringify the tmp array.

    $result = '';
    foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) {
        $result .= "$key : $value\n";
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tmp = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) $tmp[$v][] = $k;
foreach ($tmp as $k => $v) echo implode(', ', $v) . ' : ' . $k . "\n<br />";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think reversing the keys and values could be beneficial. Turn the integers into keys, and the chars into array values. This would enable you to maintain the desired one-to-many relationship:

```
$array = array(
  'a' => 65,
  'b' => 31,
  'c' => 100,
  'd' => 31,
  'e' => 31,
  'f' => 31,
  'h' => 23,
  'i' => 23,
  'j' => 23,
  'k' => 23,
  'l' => 48,
  'm' => 48,
);

$results = array();

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $results[$v][]=$k;
}


foreach ($results as $k=>$v) {
    echo implode(',',$v) . " : " . $k . "\r\n";
}
```

the multidimensional array $results equals:

```
array(5) {
  [65]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
  }
  [31]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "d"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "e"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "f"
  }
  [100]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "c"
  }
  [23]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "h"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "i"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "j"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "k"
  }
  [48]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "l"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "m"
  }
}
```

Final output:

```
a : 65
b,d,e,f : 31
c : 100
h,i,j,k : 23
l,m : 48
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$array = array('a' => 65,'b' => 31,'c' => 100,'d' => 31,'e' => 31,'f' => 31,'h' => 23,
               'i' => 23,'j' => 23,'k' => 23,'l' => 48,'m' => 48);
$similars = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    // This is my attempt among others to no luck.
    // Can not use array_key_exists because values are unpredictable.
    $key = array_search($v, $similars);
    if (isset($similars[$key])) {
        unset($similars[$key]);
        $similars[$key.','.$k] = $v;
    }
    else
        $similars[$k] = $v;
}

print_r($similars);
//display as expected
foreach($similars as $k => $v)
  echo "</br>".$k.':'.$v;
```

Comment: Thanks, but perhaps $similars should be defined first: Warning: array_search(): Wrong datatype for second argument on line 19: http://codepad.org/lkVgaHvW